# File upload without using PHP or any server-side scripting?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, web

The client wants to allow uploading of images on the local web app and the images will also be stored locally. It's more like copying the selected image file and putting it in a directory.

How can this be done using web technologies?
We cannot use PHP. (*don't ask why*)

Comment: just to clarify: you're not actually uploading anything right? i.e you are just storing pictures locally somewhere the app can find them?

Comment: yes, the app will be ran locally and the files will also be coming from the local storage. Seems weird but this is what the client wants and we're trying to look if this is possible.

Comment: a modern browser could do that for sure,  though I can't speak for mobile devices / older browsers etc. Edit: [see this for example](http://fsojs.com/)

Comment: +1 Great example. We'll surely check this. Thanks

Comment: @serakfalcon, the link you provide is broken. Can you fix it?

Comment: @SamuliKärkkäinen I guess this question still isn't answered, [this](https://github.com/cozawariat/fsoJS) seems to be the source that used to be on that page, I haven't done a serious search of other possibilities but hopefully this helps!